# Complex IIF condition in Visibility of Report item in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, visibility, iif

I have a complex visibility expression that is as below  and does not seem to work

```
=IIF((First(Fields!DeliveryTerms.Value, "PurchPurchaseOrderLine") = "1" AND ((Globals!TotalPages-1) = Globals!PageNumber)) 

OR ((First(Fields!DeliveryTerms.Value, "PurchPurchaseOrderLine") = "0" AND (Globals!TotalPages = Globals!PageNumber)), true, false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been helpful if you had provided the error that you are getting. Looking at the IIF it seems there is a mismatch between the brackets, try the one given below.

```
=IIF((First(Fields!DeliveryTerms.Value, "PurchPurchaseOrderLine") = "1" AND ((Globals!TotalPages-1) = Globals!PageNumber)) 
OR  (First(Fields!DeliveryTerms.Value, "PurchPurchaseOrderLine") = "0" AND (Globals!TotalPages = Globals!PageNumber)),true, false)
```

Comment: Thank u so much ,  there was no error as such since I was controlling visibility  , the issue was with the bracket .  thanks for the solution.